# How to model the joint distribution of continuous and discrete features (and estimate the model)?

Tags: mixed-model, maximum-likelihood, continuous-data, discrete-data

Suppose a typical house in the market has 3 features $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$. $X_1$ is the square footage of the apartments interior living space, $X_2$ is the square footage of the land space and $X_3$ is the number of bedrooms. I have a dataset of $n$ houses, i.e., $\{X_{1i},X_{2i},X_{3i}\}_{i=1}^n$. I want to use a parametric model $f(x_1,x_2,x_3;\theta)$ to model the joint distribution of $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ and estimate this model, where $\theta$ is the parameter to be estimated. Which parametric model  $f(x_1,x_2,x_3;\theta)$  is appropriate? I'm not sure how to approach it, as most often we model the joint distribution of only continuous random variables such as joint normal.

One solution I have in mind is to model it as follows:
First, I model the marginal distribution of the discrete random variable $X_3$ using distribution $g(x_3;\theta_3)$;
Second, I model the conditional distribution of $(X_1,X_2)|x_3$ as joint normal $N(\mu_{x_3},\Sigma_{x_3})$ for all possible $x_3$.

To estimate the model, I only need to estimate $\theta_3$ using the marginal distribution of $X_3$, and then estimate $N(\mu_{x_3},\Sigma_{x_3})$ separately using only observations in which $X_3=x_3$.

Does this modeling and estimation strategy sound ok? Feel free to comment if you have a better way of doing the modeling or estimation.